# Where do I get the update-java-alternatives command. What package does it come from?

Tags: java, update-alternatives

Where do I get the 'update-java-alternatives' command. What package does it come from?  My understanding is that you use 'update-alternatives' to initially add a Java instance to your system but once you have multiple instances added you can use the 'update-java-alternatives' command to flip all the symlinks using a single command.

Can anyone provide insight on where I can get this command on ANY Debian system or even a Redhat system?

Comment: Just use the `update-alternatives` command: `sudo update-alternatives --config java`

Comment: Thanks @konapun but that isn't my question.  I am asking about the 'update-java-alternatives' command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `update-java-alternatives` command is in the `java-common` package. Red Hat systems don't seem to have it.

By the way, if you ever want to use a command but you don't know what package provides it, try installing `apt-file` and use its searching powers.